# RxJs / Ngrx limit http calls for specified parameters

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an Angular service with the following method:

```
  public getItem(itemId: string): Observable<IItem> {
    if (itemId== null) {
      return of(null);
    }
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getItemFromStore(itemId)),
      tap(item=> {
        if (item=== undefined) {
          this.store.dispath(new GetItemAction({itemId: itemId}}));
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

And an effect to catch the action:

```
@Effect()
public getItem$: Observable<Action> = this.actions
    .pipe(
        ofType(ActionTypes.GET_ITEM),
        map((action: GetItemAction) => action.payload),
        exhaustMap(payload => {
            return this.httpClient.get(`api/items/` + payload.itemId).pipe(
                map(item => {
                    return new GetItemSuccessAction({ itemId: payload.itemId, item });
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                    return of(new GetItemErrorAction({ error: error }));
                })
            );
        })
    );
```

This all works fine and dandy except if I were to request two different items at the same time, the exaustMap would ignore the second item and it would never get retrieved.

How can I write this so requests for the same item are only loaded once but requests for two items at the same time will both load?

An example:

```
This.store.dispatch(new GetItemAction({itemId: '1'});
This.store.dispatch(new GetItemAction({itemId: '1'});
This.store.dispatch(new GetItemAction({itemId: '2'});
```

If all 3 actions were dispatched, there should be 2 http requests, one for item 1 and one for item 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`distinct`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinct) operator for this.

> Returns an Observable that emits all items emitted by the source Observable that are distinct by comparison from previous items.

For example:

```
const s = new Subject();

const source = s.pipe(
  distinct(p => p.id),
  concatMap(p => of(p)) // instead of `of(p)`, call the service
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

s.next({id: 1, text: 'AAA'})
s.next({id: 1, text: 'BBB'})
s.next({id: 2, text: 'CCC'})
s.next({id: 2, text: 'DDD'})
s.next({id: 1, text: 'EEE'})
s.next({id: 4, text: 'FFF'})
```

Logs:

```
{id: 1, text: "AAA"}

{id: 2, text: "CCC"}

{id: 4, text: "FFF"}
```

This would also mean you wouldn't be able to fetch `id 1` later, if this is something you want to do, you can use `groupBy`:

```
const s = new Subject();

const source = s.pipe(
  groupBy(p => p.id),
  mergeMap(p => p.pipe(
      exhaustMap(p => of(p).pipe(delay(1000))),
    )
  ),
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

s.next({id: 1, text: 'AAA'})
s.next({id: 1, text: 'BBB'})
s.next({id: 2, text: 'CCC'})
s.next({id: 2, text: 'DDD'})
s.next({id: 1, text: 'EEE'})
s.next({id: 4, text: 'FFF'})

setTimeout(() => {
  s.next({id: 1, text: 'AAA'})
}, 2000)
```

Logs:

```
{id: 1, text: "AAA"}

{id: 2, text: "CCC"}

{id: 4, text: "FFF"}

After 2 seconds:

{id: 1, text: "AAA"}
```

Comment: Either of those would result in duplicate httpcall for the same ItemId

Comment: You're updated answer with the groupBy/mergeMap/exhaustMap seemed to do the trick, thanks!